# Pass value of textBox of WEB application to Desktop application's textBox using C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, textbox

Everyone I am using C#.NET for the task. Let me explain briefly what i need actually. I have a WEB application in ASP.NET C# and the value/data inserted by the user in the '**TextBox**'(**Employee_name:**) needs to be passed to desktop application on the same corresponding '**TextBox**' say "**Employee_name:**" So how do i make it. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear... And I do not think that's possible per se.

Comment: The real question is **why**? Why do you need a desktop app that receives information in real-time from a web app? Pick the one that best suits your needs, and stick with it. If you need both, sync them up with a *database* instead of passing data the way you've suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web applications can not initiate a communication. So you can't do this the way you'd (probably like).

You can have your desktop application call a method in you ASP.NET application and get back the value and then put it in that required textbox.

However, that would mean a two step process Since you'd have to know when to ask the GUI application to go get the data from the ASP.NET application and depending on your situation, you'll probably have to pass additional information to the ASP.NET application so it can provide the value from the correct "record" as well.

**EDIT**
Simple way to achieve this, using just regular Http request (no web services or WCF)

The Mark up in an .aspx file should have no html. Just the page directive like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HttpTaskServer.WebForm1" %>
```

In your code behind file (.cs file of the page) you could do something like this:

```
  public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
      {
        //Some parameter passed in by the client via QueryString (url)
        var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        string data = GetTheData(id);
        Response.Write(data);
      }
    }
  }
```

For an example of how to make an http call from a GUI/Console application. Take a look at Code Listing 9 (the last code listing in the blog post). the link below will take you straight to code listing 9
http://www.matlus.com/httpwebrequest-asynchronous-programming/#codelisting9

Comment: How do you call a method in a ASP.NET application from a desktop application? are you referring to webservice/wcf?

Comment: From a client application you can use HttpwebRequest to make a normal http request similar to how a browser makes a call. Take a look at this blog post for some sample code. For your purpose just look at the last code listing (code listing 9) http://www.matlus.com/httpwebrequest-asynchronous-programming/.

Comment: In your ASP.NET application, If your not familiar with Http Handlers, simply use a page. Clear out all html from the aspx file. Leave the @Page directive in place, just remove html markup. Then in the Page_Load event. Simply do: Response.Write("Your Data")

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:
- A webservice (WCF?) running on the IIS
- A webservice consumer in the desktop

The desktop client polls the web server if he has something for him on a regular interval. That or use WCF to set up duplex communication. That way the server can inform his clients the textbox has been changed. The communication still needs to be initiated by the desktop client.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the scenario you are referring to here is a Front end web application and backoffice windows application. I am not sure why would need the data to be passed in real time but my suggestion would be to get your operation from Web application completed/stored in Database and then have that data pulled from DB to your windows application.